# c# data shared between threads does not update

Tags: c#, multithreading

What I'm trying to do is I draw an image in the gui thread, and I have another thread that desializes the object that has the image and sends it to tcp socket every second.
The image in the paint event is changing, but it is not changing in the tcp thread.
Here is the trimmed down code:

```
// GUI class:
private static readonly object lock_obj = new object();
private GraphicsServerReceiver server;
private Bitmap gl_image;
private void checkBoxActivateBroadcast_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBoxActivateBroadcast.Checked)
    {
        this.server = new GraphicsServerReceiver(SERVER_PORT, gl_image);
    }
}

private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // do some drawing
    lock (lock_obj)
    {
       gl_image = TakeScreenshot();
    }
}

public Bitmap TakeScreenshot()
{
    if (GraphicsContext.CurrentContext == null)
            throw new GraphicsContextMissingException();
    int w = glControl1.ClientSize.Width;
    int h = glControl1.ClientSize.Height;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data =
        bmp.LockBits(glControl1.ClientRectangle, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, glControl1.ClientSize.Width, glControl1.ClientSize.Height, PixelFormat.Bgr, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
    return bmp;
}
#----------------
# the GraphicsServerReceiver class:

private Bitmap gl_image;
private static readonly object lock_obj = new object();

public GraphicsServerReceiver(int port, Bitmap gl_image)
{
    this.port = port;
    this.gl_image = gl_image;
    this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
    this.tcpListener.Start();
    this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
    this.listenThread.Start();
}

private void ListenForClients()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Server was stopped so program failed to listen to clients. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    byte[] buffer;
    lock(lock_obj)
    {
        databag.img = gl_image;
        buffer = Serializer.ObjectToByteArray(databag);
    }
    // send the data in buffer...
}
```

It must be a multi-threading problem but I do not see it.
I've used different lock objects in the 2 classes. Could that be causing this?

Added new info:
Here is a complete code in a single file that reproduces the problem without the paint event:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static readonly object lock_obj = new object();
        private Bitmap gl_image;
        private GraphicsServerReceiver server;
        private bool server_running = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!server_running)
            {
                lock (lock_obj)
                {
                    gl_image = new Bitmap("C:/temp/x.bmp");
                }
                this.server = new GraphicsServerReceiver(gl_image);
                btn1.Text = "stop";
            }
            else
            {
                server.stop();
                btn1.Text = "start";
            }
            server_running = !server_running;
        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // change the image
            lock (lock_obj)
            {
                // draw a line:
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(gl_image))
                {
                    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
                    graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, 0, 50, 50);
                }
                gl_image.Save("C:/temp/changed.bmp");
            }
        }

    }

    class GraphicsServerReceiver
    {
        private Bitmap gl_image;
        private static readonly object lock_obj = new object();
        private Thread listenThread;

        public void stop()
        {
            listenThread.Abort();
            listenThread.Join(1);
        }

        public GraphicsServerReceiver(Bitmap gl_image)
        {
            this.gl_image = gl_image;
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }

        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start("some param");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void HandleClientComm(object useless_obj)
        {
            while (listenThread.IsAlive)
            {
                lock (lock_obj)
                {
                    gl_image.Save("C:/temp/out.bmp");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks that your this.gl_image refers to the image which was once passed to `GraphicsServerReceiver` ctor, while `TakeScreenshot` creates a new one afterwards.

Comment: The reference to gl_image in the GraphicsServerReceiver will always be the first image passed it.  After 'TakeScreenshot" you need to update the server reference.

Comment: what you guys say makes sense. I added the code for TakeScreenshot. How do I just change the reference in such a way that the second reference to my first image reference gets updated? Do I need the 'ref' keyword?

Comment: @max: Check option #2 in my answer below. You can add a property in GraphicsServerReceiver through which you can update the Bitmap instance.

Comment: @max `ref` would not help. You may pass an object which contains `gl_image`. (As a cheap solution, just to see if it works, you may pass an array of `Bitmaps` which has just one element, `gl_image`. Then if you update the element of the array in one class, the second class can access it.).

Comment: @AlexD You were right. using ref did not help. Any other ideas?

Comment: @max Try to make a container class which has `gl_image` as its property. Pass that class instead of passing `gl_image`. (You may even try `Bitmap[]` array with one element, as I wrote.)

Comment: why are you using the graphics.DrawLine approach? It will be more complex, since you need to be in the right event to "paint" something directly on the canvas. I suggest you use the PictoreBox.Image control. It handles the GDI internals of painting something on canvas. The problem here is that you're painting something in the wrong event. To paint on canvas, you should use OnPaint event. If you don't want to handles the internal of how to paint, the PictureBox control can help you.

Comment: @EricLemes As I said, that's just to demonstrate the problem where I draw a line on the image and save it as changed.bmp to prove that the image has changed. My actual code is much more complex and uses openGL in the paint event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: Instead of using the gl_image and then putting a lock on it, I made a update_image method in my server and I call that whenever I draw something new. This works.

However, I still do not know the reason why my reference was not getting updated in the other approach that I first tried so if anyone can explain that correctly, I'd appretiate and up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the OnPaint event to redraw the image. Unless you minimize your window, move or do something that internally fires WM_PAINT, you're image will never be draw.

A suggestion is after you receive the image from the server, you call:

```
yourControl.Invoke(InvalidateControl);

public void InvalidateControl(){
  yourControl.Invalidate();
}
```

The "Invoke" is needed to change something in the GUI from other thread. You can also use an Image Control and just update the image instead of using the OnPaint event.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful; however, I already know this and that's what I want. Whenever something new is painted, then I want to  update the image and sent it.

Comment: I've posted a new code that reproduces the problem in a more simple way. You press btn1 to start the server. Press btn2 to change the image. The server thread writes the image to the local disk every second. You can see that it does not change. You'd expect out.bmp to be identical to changed.bmp